# MongoDB - How to build query string with [Object] as a field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm building up a string in Meteor to drill down into my data from MongoDB.

My data looks like this:

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfJQx.png)

In my Meteor projects JavaScript I have built up the string like so:

```
const concentrationTier1 = MyCollection.findOne({_id: "85gh43tnb23v4"}).BILL.Sovereign.USD.Short.Low.High.N.ARGENTINA.IssueName00006.ARARGE5203E7;
        console.log(concentrationTier1);
```

But now in my console it is returning the following:

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZKJe.png)

How would I add [Object] to my string to be able to display the next part of the data?

I have tried .[Object] .Object .0 and of course these didn't work.

Can any body help with this one?

Many thanks,

G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to access that array element as in plain normal javascript, like this:

```
...IssueName00006.ARARGE5203E7[0].concentrationTier1
```

And the reason is your MongoDB query already returned a document, you're not querying in your database anymore so there's no need to use dot notation to access array elements.